# Passing an image as a function parameter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, grayscale

I am trying to pass an image file as a function parameter in python but there is an error in it and I can't see the possible cause of it. I have to convert this image to grayscaleand show it as an output if g = 1 else I have to output the same image as it is. I have saved the code at the same place where I have stored the image.

```
import cv2

def color_grayscale(filename, g):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    grayscale_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if g==1:
        img = grayscale_img
    cv2.imshow('image',img)

color_grayscale('test_img1.jpg',1)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/NOOR BRAR/Documents/College Stuff/5th SEM/e-yantra/task1/PS1_Task1/Task1_Practice/test_images/coeinsog", line 10, in <module>
color_grayscale('test_img1.jpg',1)
File "C:/Users/NOOR BRAR/Documents/College Stuff/5th SEM/e-yantra/task1/PS1_Task1/Task1_Practice/test_images/coeinsog", line 5, in color_grayscale
grayscale_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: I've added the error message @AndrasDeak

Comment: try `img = cv2.imread(filename,g)`

Comment: Is it possible that your image doesn't have the right amount of channels?

Comment: Didn't work @Valijon

Comment: I tried another image @AndrasDeak. Now the problem is that only the window named image appears but no image is showed and after some time it becomes unresponsive.

Comment: And did you fix according to my first comment?

Comment: then there is another error which is:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NOOR BRAR/Documents/College Stuff/5th SEM/e-yantra/task1/PS1_Task1/Task1_Practice/test_images/coeinsog.py", line 13, in <module>
    color_grayscale('lion.jpg' ,1)
  File "C:/Users/NOOR BRAR/Documents/College Stuff/5th SEM/e-yantra/task1/PS1_Task1/Task1_Practice/test_images/coeinsog.py", line 9, in color_grayscale
    cv2.imshow(img)
TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found

Comment: Dang, sorry, I falsely assumed that `cv2.imshow` has similar syntax to `plt.imshow`. Nevermind me then:)